# Whats is better in swift: a function returning a variable or just a getter variable

Tags: ios, swift, properties

In swift I can create a method like -

**#1**

```
func baseURL() -> String {
    #if DEBUG
        return "https://debug.myserver.url.com"
    #else
        return "https://production.myserver.url.com"
    #endif

}
```

I can also write it in this way -

**#2**

```
var baseURL:String {
    #if DEBUG
        return "https://debug.myserver.url.com"
    #else
        return "https://production.myserver.url.com"
    #endif
}
```

The requirement of declaring a get only property is met by both methods. Personally I find the second method better cos of readablility.

I know its not too much of a difference, but I'd still like to know which one is better? Does either method have any advantage over the other?

Comment: "Personally I find the second method better cos of readablility" Then the second one is better.

Comment: Usually I prefer computed properties because you can call them without the `()`. However IMHO the rule of thumb seems to be: use computed property when you don't have to create complex objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does either method have any advantage over the other?

Not internally, no. A computed property *is* a function, so there is no difference in implementation under the hood.

Comment: I agree with Matt. I use vars when doing something that requires almost no work (checking states of variables to see which value should be used) but if you are doing work I recommend creating a func instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply getting a value with minimal computation, such as your example, then a getter is a good option.

If getting the value could do some heavy computation or modifies any members on the class, then a function is preferable.